# Table has a composite primary key which is not supported by crud generator

Tags: yii

Table 'Media_Key' has a composite primary key which is not supported by crud generator.

Why is this happening?

Using the crud generator tool

My DB tables looks like this

```
MEDIA                     MEDIA_KEY              KEYWORD
 media_pk  ------------|    ID            |------ keyword_pk
                       --<  media_fk      |
                            keyword_fk  >--
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Media_Key's foreign keys (media_fk and/or keyword_fk) are included into table's primary key. Try to drop PK, recreate it with only ID column, recreate model and then use crud generator again. Or maybe it'll be more reasonable to create controller for MediaKey model manually.